# R NAMESPACE export pattern using Perl style (non-consuming regular expression)

Tags: r, regex

I want to export all functions from an R-package calle myPackageId that do not start with a period and do not start with string "myPackageId_". 
Functions with the second pattern are automatically generated by Rcpp in C-code as "RcppExport SEXP myPackageId_cFunctionname" that should not be exported by the package.

I found a solution using non-consuming regular expression:

```
exportPattern("(?=^[^\\.])(?=^(?!myPackageId_))")
```

This works with R grep with option perl=TRUE. However, default R grep with extended RE and R CMD INSTALL complain about an invalid pattern.

```
words <- c(".test","test","myPackageId_test")
grep("(?=^[^\\.])(?=^(?!myPackageId_))",words, perl=TRUE)
grep("(?=^[^\\.])(?=^(?!myPackageId_))",words)
```

In the above example, the word "test" would be accepted, whereas the other words ".test" and "myPackageId_test" would not be accepted.

Expected inputs are all [valid R names](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Identifiers). These are the usual words composed of ASCII characters without whitespace. In R also the period, ".", can start a name.

Is there a pattern that I can use with grep option perl=FALSE to achieve the same goal?
Or can I tell R somehow in the NAMESPACE file to use the perl variant with grep?

Comment: Can you give a definitive list of valid and invalid inputs that you expect to encounter?

Comment: @CAustin, I provided a link to desription of expected inputs in the edited post.